# Java Date format : String to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a String date I am converting to a `XMLGregorianCalendar`.  The below code converts it with no errors.  However, the system I pass the date to, gets the error reported below.

The following `XMLGregorianCalendar` works:

[image]

The following `XMLGregorianCalendar` does not work (the code below converts it to this):

[image]

**Question**

How do I convert the string to the required format?

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    try {
        String commenceTOString = "2021-06-30 05:00:00";
        java.util.Date dateCommence = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(commenceTOString);
        System.out.println(dateCommence);
        java.util.GregorianCalendar c = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(dateCommence);
        
        javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar commence = javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
        System.out.println(commence);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Error

> E: Message validation failed. Errors: [cvc-pattern-valid: Value
> '2021-06-30T06:30:00.000+02:00' is not facet-valid with respect to
> pattern
> '(((((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-9])))|((((0[13578])|(1[02]))-31)|(((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2]))-30)))|(((19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))-02-29))|((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9]))-((((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8])))|((((0[13578])|(1[02]))-31)|(((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2]))-(29|30)))))T([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){1,2}'
> for type 'dateTime'.cvc-attribute.3: The value
> '2021-06-30T06:30:00.000+02:00' of attribute 'DepartureDateTime' on
> element 'FlightSegment' is not valid with respect to its type,
> 'dateTime'.].
> http://www.elleipsis.com/booking/exception/35a8ac87-6743-4719-9504-a8a17a1a0471

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Similar: [XMLGregorianCalendar in java, with NO Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564200/xmlgregoriancalendar-in-java-with-no-timezone).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Generally I recommend that you use java.time for your date and time work, also when there is no direct conversion between java.time classes and `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

### The hack

The hack is simply to edit the `T` into the string that `XMLGregorianCalendar` expects to be there and then parse the modified string directly. Then we neither need java.time nor `Date` nor `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    String commenceTOString = "2021-06-30 05:00:00";
    XMLGregorianCalendar commence = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(commenceTOString.replace(' ', 'T'));
    System.out.println(commence);
```

Output:

> 2021-06-30T05:00:00

### Convert via String

Parse into `LocalDateTime`, format into a string in the format `XMLGregorianCalendar` knows and let the `DatatypeFactory` parse again:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(commenceTOString, parser);
    XMLGregorianCalendar commence = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateTime.format(formatter));
    System.out.println(commence);
```

Output is the same as before.

### Convert via numbers

Though a few lines longer this is the conceptually simple conversion: transfer each field from `LocalDateTime` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar commence = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                    dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonthValue(), dateTime.getDayOfMonth(), 
                    dateTime.getHour(), dateTime.getMinute(), dateTime.getSecond(),
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    System.out.println(commence);
```

Output is still the same.

### Convert via GregorianCalendar

I believe that this is the official conversion: convert to `ZonedDateTime` to `GregorianCalendar` and finally to `XMLGregorianCalendar`. We need to set the unwanted field to `FIELD_UNDEFINED` just as in your own answer.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(commenceTOString, parser)
            .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(dateTime);
    XMLGregorianCalendar commence = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    commence.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    commence.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    System.out.println(commence);
```

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: (using `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`)

```
           GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.setTime(dateCommence);
            XMLGregorianCalendar commence = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
            commence.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            commence.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```